# Running django + apache in localhost windows

Tags: python, django

i wanna try using apache as a server for django, i already add a code in the bottom httpd.conf like this

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /D:/CodeTesting/Django/project1/project1/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome /C:/Users/Fatoni/Envs/django
WSGIPythonPath /D:/CodeTesting/Django/project1

<Directory /D:/CodeTesting/Django/project1/project1>
   <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
   </Files>
</Directory>
```

note: i have changed documentroot apache into d:/ and i am using virtualenv in development, i am also using apache through xampp.

did i make a mistake in that configuration, what kind of thing that i should do to run django in apache locally?

it showing error like this after i added that code

```
10:06:05  [Apache]  Status change detected: running
10:06:07  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
10:06:07  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:06:07  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:06:07  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:06:07  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:06:07  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:06:07  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:06:07  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: The error that you posted here contains troubleshooting instructions. When you followed them, what was the result?

Comment: [Thu Mar 07 09:37:23.742501 2019] [core:error] [pid 8248:tid 1960] (OS 5)Access is denied.  : [client ::1:5494] AH00127: Cannot map GET / HTTP/1.1 to file @JosephSible